# "Certificate size exceeds limit" error in SSO with AWS service

Tags: amazon-web-services, webex, aws-cloud9, aws-ses

I an have an error in SSO with AWS service,
when uploading XML from Cisco Webex to AWS SSO service:

> #### An error occurred
>
> Your request has a problem. 
>   Please see the following details.
>
> **Certificate size 2720 exceeds limit: 2000**

> AWS SSO works as an Identity Provider (IdP)
>   for any SAML 2.0-compliant cloud applications. 
>   To configure this application for SSO access,
>   you must establish a trust relationship between AWS SSO
>   and your cloud application (service provider)
>   through a SAML metadata exchange. …

[image: Certificate size exceeds limit error]

> #### when i click on
>
> **"if you don't have a metadata file you can manually type your metadata 
>    values"**
>
> #### i don't know what this values and how to get her

[image: this]

#### this link for explain all thing with webex [enter from here](https://static.global.sso.amazonaws.com/app-3f90bce2164c7fb2/instructions/index.htm?metadata=https%3A%2F%2Fportal.sso.us-east-2.amazonaws.com%2Fsaml%2Fmetadata%2FNzIzMjA1NzU2OTgxX2lucy1hMTczNGMxNmFlYWRiNDZk&signin_url=https%3A%2F%2Fportal.sso.us-east-2.amazonaws.com%2Fsaml%2Fassertion%2FNzIzMjA1NzU2OTgxX2lucy1hMTczNGMxNmFlYWRiNDZk&signout_url=https%3A%2F%2Fportal.sso.us-east-2.amazonaws.com%2Fsaml%2Flogout%2FNzIzMjA1NzU2OTgxX2lucy1hMTczNGMxNmFlYWRiNDZk&issuer_url=https%3A%2F%2Fportal.sso.us-east-2.amazonaws.com%2Fsaml%2Fassertion%2FNzIzMjA1NzU2OTgxX2lucy1hMTczNGMxNmFlYWRiNDZk&idp_certificate=https%3A%2F%2Fus-east-2.console.aws.amazon.com%2Fsinglesignon%2Fhome%3F%23applications%2Fins-a1734c16aeadb46d%2FdownloadIdPCert)

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: I think you'll have to ask Amazon for support. Try typing the metadata file manually. Why does the error refer to a certificate size but you are uploading a metadata file?

Comment: i don't know why this !

Comment: see second photo please